# Link to file in Fluid – how to specify storage?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-7.x

As far as I know, there's no such thing as an `f:link.file` or `v:link.file` viewhelper.

There used to be a solution using `file.originalResource.publicUrl` as the value to point the link to, as in

```
<f:link.page pageUid="{file.originalResource.publicUrl}" target="_blank">
```

Am I right that this is no longer necessary? I got this (using `ext:mask`):

```
<f:link.page pageUid="{file.identifier}" target="_blank">
```

returning the same value, while `originalResource.publicUrl` would not even show up in `f:debug`.

BUT in `file.identifier` the storage path, e.g. `fileadmin`, is not present. How do I add it to the viewhelper?

Or, what is the currently recommended solution for a link to a file in TYPO3 7.6?

Comment: See below at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69551991/160968 – now there is a VH for TYPO3 11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TYPO3 11 introduced a new ViewHelper for this

`<f:link.file file="{file}" target="_blank">Download</f:link.file>`

https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/11.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Link/File.html

Answer (score 12):

Just use `<a href="{file.publicUrl}">{file.name}</a>`. When absolute URL or some special configuration is needed use `<f:link.typolink parameter="{file.publicUrl}">{file.name}</f:link.typolink>`.

Comment: yess, thanks! Why don't I get that property with `<f:debug>{file}</f:debug>`? It only gives me `propertiesOfFileReference, name, mergedProperties, uidOfFileReference, originalFile`

Answer (score 2):

For me, @minifranske’s solution worked only as a hint: I needed to use `{file.originalResource.publicUrl}` instead:

```
<f:link.typolink parameter="{file.originalResource.publicUrl}">{file.originalResource.title}</f:link.typolink>
```

also available:

```
{file.originalResource.name}
{file.originalResource.description}
{file.originalResource.alternative}
```

Nevertheless, if anybody knows a proper core solution which resembles that of the Rich Text Editor, I’d be happy to hear about it:

```
<a href="t3://file?uid=123">file link</a>
<a href="t3://page?uid=123">page link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<f:uri.image image="{imageObject}" />` produces the path + filename for your FAL object.

Comment: This produces the path to a rendered image of my PDF file – I just want a link to it